# Vaadin8: How to display Vaadin icon inside TextField?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin8

Using Vaadin 8 I want to display the Vaadin search icon inside the TextField on the left side.

```
    TextField search = new TextField("");
    search.setPlaceholder("Search target");
    search.setIcon(VaadinIcons.SEARCH);
    search.addStyleName("search");
```

With this code the icon is displayed above the TextField. I think I need to add some CSS code in the mytheme.scss file such as

```
    .v-icon-search {
       display: inline;
}
```

But this did not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a predefined styles in `ValoTheme` for this purpose:

```
search.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TEXTFIELD_INLINE_ICON);
```